# Angular Fullstack is not working for Yomen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meanjs

events.js:160

```
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

Error: Cannot find module 'generator-ng-component/generators/route'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
at child.compose (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/generators/route/index.js:7:92)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:439:23)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:440:9
at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5)
```

Comment: Sorry - but what exactly is the question here? What have you tried so far? I'm not familiar with Angular Fullstack? Is that an open source framework of some kind? Did you open an issue with them? Did you `npm install`? (Is `generator-ng-component/generators/route` even in your package.json or is it expected to be installed globally?) I'm just throwing darts here.

Answer (score 0):

It is my guess that it's an issue with the [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) generators.
I have been encountering the same issue when performing the following command:

```
yo angular-fullstack:route [myroute]
```

[angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) generators  are now integrating Angular2, but may not be fully finished. For example, endpoints are working

```
yo angular-fullstack:enpoint [myendpoint]
```

I assume this because the code for generator-angular-fullstack/generators/endpoint or generator-angular-fullstack/generators/component look very different than generator-angular-fullstack/generators/route.

Unfortunately, this isn't a solution. If I am correct, I guess we can either wait for an update or create new routes manually for now.

EDIT: generator-angular-fullstack@5.0.0-alpha.3.